# How to run celery beat as daemon?

Tags: python, django, celerybeat

I know there is a command for celeryd to run as daemon, i.e; celeryd_detach. But how can I run celery-beat as daemon using any command? Please help me in this.

TIA

Answer (score 2):

Just place this [script](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/extra/generic-init.d/celerybeat) under `/etc/init.d/` and then you will be able to do the `service celerybeat {start|stop|restart stuff}`.

More doc: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/daemonizing.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried as you told, but beat scheduler is not executing its tasks.

Comment: is it starting? if it's starting but not executing the tasks you should check the configuration you have for celery under /etc/default/{celerybeat|celery}. The second link you have in my post explains you how to couple celery working as a daemon with your Django project (you need to tell celery where to find your project).

Comment: Hello, trying to run the beat scheduler as a daemon, but when running service celerybeat start I get: Failed to start celerybeat.service: Unit celerybeat.service failed to load: No such file or directory.

Answer (score 0):

celery -A your-project beat --detach -l info -f beat.log